# In TypeScript infer generic types of callback from argument

Tags: typescript

There are a bunch of SO questions that match this title description, but as far as I know, none of them answer this question.

I'm trying to write a wrapper around an express `RequestHandler` that catches errors in async handlers and calls `next` with that error.

The idea is I can do something like:

```ts
function tryCatchNext<
  P = ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
  Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
>(
  callback: RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>
): RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals> {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
}

app.get('/:foo', tryCatchNext(async (req, res, next) => {
  // `foo` is not a known parameter, but no error
  if (req.params.foo === 'bar') {
    throw new Error('That was a bar.');
  }

  // does not result in an error
  // @ts-expect-error
  console.log(req.params.bar);

  res.send('Not a bar');
}));
```

If I just have the handler, `req` knows its `params`.  Within `tryCatchNext()` `req` doesn't.  I suspect it's because it's trying to infer the return value from the callback passed into it rather than the generic types of its context.

It works perfectly if I do prefix it with a no-op handler, so that `.get()`'s `...handlers` rest parameter is already inferred.

```ts
app
  .get('/:foo', (req, res, next) => next(), tryCatchNext(async (req, res, next) => {
    // ...
  }));
```

Is there a way to get around this without explicitly specifying each of the generic type parameters?

Comment: Please share reproducable example with highlighted error

Comment: Working on it, but there is no error because the default `req.params` is just a `Record<string, string>`.

Comment: Sure, just comment the line where you have an issue

Comment: I know your pain ))

Comment: Did you try to overload `app.get` ?

Comment: In order to do what?  I'm not sure what overload I would add.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a wrapper done specificly for the express `RequestHandler` you may just want to use the `Parameters` utility type ([doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)) to get the type of the callback accepted as second parameter of `app.get` function, this way:

```
type CallbackType = Parameters<typeof app.get>[1];

function tryCatchNext( callback: CallbackType ): CallbackType {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
}
```

I guess that digging into the type definition you may find better typings ([doc](https://github.com/types/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.d.ts#L81)), but I think this should work